# Trying to import a JSON file into React but not working

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import a JSON object from a js file in my React project. I am a newbie to React so please go easy :). I keep getting an error no matter what path I change it to (cannot be found). I've attached a screengrab of the directory structure.  I am in the scripts/components folder in the home.js file. Thanks. Data is the object in the JSON file imported from the "server" folder.

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../server/data';


class Home extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <section id="home">
            <div className="content">
                <p>Test...</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
  }
}

// Export out the React Component
module.exports = Home;
```

[image]

Comment: your file is on server side, move it into the `app` folder

Comment: Can you show us how data.js look like? Do you export it?

Comment: this should solve import data from '../../../server/data' if you are using export default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go three directories up.

1. `../` takes you to `scripts`.
2. `../../` takes you to `app`.
3. `../../../` takes you to the project root.

thus,

```
import data from '../../../server/data';
```